GSConnect can't find any device
I want to connect my laptop(I'm using Ubuntu 24.10) and my android phone together. The problem is GSConnect is not showing any device.
I tried connecting them using KDE Connect on Windows 11 and it worked but I couldn't connect using GSConnect or KDE Connect on Ubuntu.
I also tried connecting manually using IP Address, guess what!? it didn't work either.

I tried a all of the solutions i found across the web but I non of them worked for me.
It fixed by just uninstalling Ubuntu 24.10 and installing Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. it's also smoother and faster than 24.10!
